# Grab Specific elements from a List after reading a file

Tags: python, readfile

I am using Python and I have a text file with results from a previous complex code. It wrote to a file called 'results' structured by:

```
xml file name.xml

['chebi:28726', 'chebi:27466', 'chebi:27721', 'chebi:15532', 'chebi:15346']

xml file name.xml

['chebi:27868', 'chebi:27668', 'chebi:15471', 'chebi:15521', 'chebi:15346']

xml file name.xml

['chebi:28528', 'chebi:28325', 'chebi:10723', 'chebi:28493', 'chebi:15346']

etc...
```

my current code is:

```
file = open("results.txt", "r")

data = file.readlines()

for a in data:

    print(a)
```

The problem is I want to grab the specific elements within that list, for example `chebi:28528`, and convert them from their current compounds into a different format. I wrote the code for this conversion already, but am having trouble with the step before the actual conversion of the compounds.

The problem is that I need to be able to loop through the file and select each element from that list but I am unable to do so.

If i do

```
for a in data:

    for b in a:
```

It selects each individual character and not the entire word (`chebi:28528`).

Is there a way I can loop through the text file and grab just the specific Chebi compounds so that I can then convert them into a different format needed? Python is treating the entire list of compounds as 1 elements, and indexing within that list will just correspond to a character rather than the compound.

Comment: You're doing `for a in data:` already, right? Look at what the strings are from `a`. You can then use various string functions (e.g. `str.find()`, or regex, and maybe `eval()`, though be very careful with this) to examine, modify, and do what you want with the list.

Comment: To turn the strings you've given into lists, I'd do something like `[s.strip() for s in a[1:-1].split(',')]`, which would leave me with roughly a python version of the list that *was* in string form.

Comment: Check out [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and try `for b in ast.literal_eval(a)` as your inner loop statement.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming that your file is as above, it looks like you have lists in raw test format. You can loop on those word elements by converting them to Python lists using ast or something similar.

You had the right ideas but you're looping through characters actually. How about this?

```
import ast

with open('results.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()


for line in data:
    if '[' not in line:
        continue

    ls = ast.literal_eval(line)

    for word in ls:
        if 'chebi' in word:
            process_me(word)
```